# SET @myxml.modify not working with leading node Has <leadnode xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2">

Tags: xml, t-sql

Thanks to a lot of help from here i have my update working to a point.
if i do not have the xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2" in the xml all works greate but i am receiveing the xml with xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2" in the lead node. Why does my modify not work with this xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2"

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml
SET @myDoc =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncReceiveDelivery xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2">
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID>infor.azure.azure_prd</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID>External</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2022-12-30T08:44:36.267</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor.azure_application_to_AIM_ReceiveDelivery:xyz1234:2022-12-30T08:44:36.267</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <Sync>
      <TenantID>AIM_PRD</TenantID>
      <AccountingEntityID>5140</AccountingEntityID>
      <Location>5140</Location>
      <ActionCriteria>
        <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
      </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <ReceiveDelivery>
      <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
        <DocumentID>
          <ID>xyz1234</ID>
        </DocumentID>
        <DocumentDateTime>2022-12-28T11:46:13.7300000</DocumentDateTime>
        <Description>3P Manifest - xyz1234</Description>
        <Status>
          <Code>Pending</Code>
          <Description>Pending</Description>
          <EffectiveDateTime>2022-12-30T14:44:36.3343520Z</EffectiveDateTime>
        </Status>
        <PackingSlip>xyz1234</PackingSlip>
      </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Classes" sequence="1">*</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <ServiceIndicator/>
        <PurchaseOrderReference>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="9991" lid="lid://infor.eam.aim_prd" location="9991">14500000999</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        </PurchaseOrderReference>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="EA">44</ReceivedQuantity>
        <LineNumber>63</LineNumber>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="UDFCHAR02">S00603851</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="UDFCHAR03">1</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Classes" sequence="1">*</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <ServiceIndicator/>
        <PurchaseOrderReference>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="9991" lid="lid://infor.eam.aim_prd" location="9991">14500000999</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        </PurchaseOrderReference>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="EA">100</ReceivedQuantity>
        <LineNumber>51</LineNumber>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="UDFCHAR02">S00603851</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="UDFCHAR03">1</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Classes" sequence="1">*</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <ServiceIndicator/>
        <PurchaseOrderReference>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="9991" lid="lid://infor.eam.aim_prd" location="9991">14500000999</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        </PurchaseOrderReference>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="EA">100</ReceivedQuantity>
        <LineNumber>75</LineNumber>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="UDFCHAR02">S00603851</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="UDFCHAR03">1</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Classes" sequence="1">*</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <ServiceIndicator/>
        <PurchaseOrderReference>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="9991" lid="lid://infor.eam.aim_prd" location="9991">15000000999</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        </PurchaseOrderReference>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="EA">100</ReceivedQuantity>
        <LineNumber>75</LineNumber>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="UDFCHAR02">S00603851</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="UDFCHAR03">1</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
    </ReceiveDelivery>
  </DataArea>
</SyncReceiveDelivery>'

declare @po nvarchar(50)
declare @poline nvarchar(10)
declare @reqline nvarchar(10)

set @po = '14500000999'
set @poline = '1'
set @reqline = '63'

      select  @myDoc 

          SET @myDoc.modify('replace value of 
    (/SyncReceiveDelivery/DataArea/ReceiveDelivery/ReceiveDeliveryItem[LineNumber[text()=sql:variable("@reqline")]]
        [PurchaseOrderReference/DocumentID/ID[text()=sql:variable("@po")]]
        [PurchaseOrderReference/LineNumber[text()=sql:variable("@poline")]]/ReceivedQuantity/text())[1]
with "99"')
```

removing the xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2" works but I receive the xml from a vendor with it so I need to fix the modify/replace to work with xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2"

Comment: any help with this issue?